# Could not load main class

Tags: java

```
package org;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
//Few more

public class QueueSend
{
  public final static String JNDI_FACTORY="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";
  public final static String JMS_FACTORY="QCF";
  public final static String QUEUE="TestQ";

  private QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory;
  private QueueConnection qcon; 
  private QueueSession qsession;
  private QueueSender qsender;
  private Queue queue;
  private TextMessage msg;

 public void init(Context ctx, String queueName)
    throws NamingException, JMSException
{
   qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
   qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
   qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
   queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(queueName);
   qsender = qsession.createSender(queue);
   msg = qsession.createTextMessage();
   qcon.start();
}

    public void send(String message) throws JMSException {
    msg.setText(message);
    qsender.send(msg);
    }

    public void close() throws JMSException {
    qsender.close();
    qsession.close();
    qcon.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 1) {
    System.out.println("Usage: java QueueSend WebLogicURL");
    return;
    }
    InitialContext ic = getInitialContext(args[0]);
    QueueSend qs = new QueueSend();
    qs.init(ic, QUEUE);
    readAndSend(qs);
    qs.close();
    }

    private static void readAndSend(QueueSend qs) throws IOException, JMSException
    {
    String line="Test Message Body with counter = ";
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    boolean readFlag=true;
    System.out.println("\n\tStart Sending Messages (Enter QUIT to Stop):\n");
    while(readFlag)
    {
    System.out.print("&lt;Msg_Sender&gt; ");
    String msg=br.readLine();
    if(msg.equals("QUIT") || msg.equals("quit"))
    {
    qs.send(msg);
    System.exit(0);
    }
    qs.send(msg);
    System.out.println();
    }
    br.close();
    }

    private static InitialContext getInitialContext(String url) throws NamingException
    {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    return new InitialContext(env);
    }
    }
```

[From this link](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=1987)

Directory structure

```
 org 
   QueueSend.java

 pwd

   /path-to/org
```

Compile

```
 javac QueueSend.java
```

Creates class file inside org

```
 cd ..

 pwd

     parent of org
```

Run

```
 java QueueSend t3://localhost:7001
```

Could not find or load main class error

Then i moved inside ord

```
 cd org
```

Execute the same run command and got the same error. I understand that we must use `fully qulaified name` it is `org.QueueSend` But i am missing something

What could be the reason? How to solve this?

Comment: Is it `java Queuesend t3` or `java QueueSend t3` ?

Comment: Did you use the fully qualified name or not?

Comment: @GopsAB I find it odd that you're working on WebLogic middleware without knowing how to compile and run a Java class from the commandline. Anyway, here's the [basics.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html)

Comment: @Kayaman Great Insult. However, Thanks.

Comment: @GopsAB It's not an insult. You're working on an advanced issue, yet you first had problems with this, and you posted another question which involved classpath issues (so I assume you managed to run the program?). I gave you a link to the Oracle Tutorial which explains both Netbeans and commandline compilation/execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `java -cp ./ org.QueueSend t3://localhost:7001`. The package name is a part of the classname. And also you have to add the actual path to the classpath, so the jre look is it for classes.

Comment: @GopsAB Have changed my answer. you alse have to add the actual path to your classpath.

Comment: can you Show the file structure? where your class files located what are the package names.

Comment: @GopsAB and you call it from the directory where org is located?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typing error -- capital S.

Your class and Java file have QueueSend.  Your run command has Queuesend.

Comment: Sorry it's a typo here. Not in my compiler. So it doesn't help